# Maven, cyclic imports, classpath for compile

Tags: maven, maven-3

I have task to migrate legacy project from ant to maven and have trouble with cyclic imports. My problem is ant builds many jars that contains same classes.

Originally ant project have one src folder and contains all packages there. For maven compatibility me require to split src folder to several modules with pom.xml (as says in guides and manuals).

Fast example.

```
Foo.java
package myapp;
import my.domain.myapp.Bar;
...

Bar.java
import my.domain.myapp.Foo;
...

src/my/domain/myapp/foo/foo.java (foo.jar)
src/my/domain/myapp/bar/bar.java (bar.jar)
```

There 2 packages placed in same parent package and no problems with compilation. Ant project just compile java classes and then generate artifacts by patterns. So, compiled *.class just copying to jar. For maven i did't see same way, i suppose me need to split packages like:

```
pom.xml (parent)
--foo
----src/main/java/my/domain/myapp/foo/foo.java
----pom.xml
--bar
----src/main/java/my/domain/myapp/bar/bar.java
----pom.xml
```

So, in maven i know only about set dependency as jar to another jar. In my case i've cyclic imports that locks build. I can't build foo.jar without bar.jar and vice versa.

Maven have something to specify class path variable for compilation process instead set dependency to jar? Some workaround?

Best practice are welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing that you need to be aware of when you are using Maven is, Maven required your components of your project (JARs, WARs, or other kind of modules) to be clearly defined.  Clear, non-cyclic dependency is one of the prerequisites.

If you faced problem because of cyclic dependency, there are something you need to look into:
(answer of @matsev provides quite some ways and I am adding some )

1. Are `foo` and `bar` really appropriate to split into separate module, if they need to be so closely coupled?
2. If you think they should be put into separate module, then you need to refactor your code.  There are lots of different ways to solve your problem, depending on your actual situation:

   - Introduce interfaces so that Foo and Bar are using corresponding interface, and you can put the interfaces into separate modules (call it foo-api or bar-api)
   - Double dispatching
   - any other patterns that help you design Foo and Bar properly to give a clear relationships between Foo and Bar.  No one can really tell you what to do as it depends on your need.  Only one thing is clear: there are area for improvement for design.  It is giving big bad smell now.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest that you refactor the code to break the circular dependency. Depending on the project, different strategies can be used:

- Does both `Foo` and `Bar` really need to know about each other? By removing one of the dependencies one of the classes will be in control. It knows it own state and at the same time it can ask for the current state of an instance of the other class.
- Use [dependency injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection) to break break the dependencies (e.g. by introducing a new `Baz` the `foo` package, let `Foo` depend on `Baz`, remove the dependency from the `foo` project to the `bar` project, and let `Bar` implement `Baz`).
- Introduction of the [observer pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern) can decouple your classes without loosing track of changes.